# ViewController versus ModalViewController

Tags: iphone, ios

What can be the differences between a ViewController and a ModalViewController ios iPhone ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no such class ModalViewController, Modal is just a way you present your UIViewController.
You can push view controller to the navigation controller stack:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Or present it in the modal way:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Apple suggest to use the way with the "completion" block.

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Satisfied With your Answer..But Can u please tell me For what purpose "completion" block is used in presentViewController ?

Comment: It's a callback of a function, if you want to perform additional tasks after the function completes.

Comment: Okay...Is it true that completion handler is called after the viewDidAppear method ?

Answer (score 2):

When we push one class from another class using modal way then the controller known as

modalviewcontroller & when we simply call a controller by push method then its simply known as

viewcontroller.